# Django template for native ios application

Tags: ios, django, django-templates

I am designing the backend for an ios app with django. As I was learning django, I came across django template which is a major part of the Django MVC/MTV architecture. Most tutorial/books I come across explains django-template with respect to generating the html(view) of a Website. For native application for ios/android, do I need django template? Or should I just pass plain data(string) from my backend to the mobile device where my native application-code will parse through the string and will display data in respective views which have been created on the client side? Basically, how should I use django template for a django-ios backend-frontend project? Is it just an optional stuff?

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a native app, then you don't need to use django templates, just build an API which your app will consume. It could send text data, or json or anything. And one you have an API in place, and want to offer your app on the web, then you could build a one page webapp that consumes the same API used by your native apps, so less work.

Comment: adding on to @elssar's point, have a look at this: http://nthn.me/posts/2008/creating-basic-api-django.html. Good starter...

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by "just build an API which your app will consume......". Do you mean, I should have some library or something similar such that once I send MY STYLE of text from the backend, the frontend can MAP my string-parts to individual views. Something like this? How about just parsing the strings we get from backend and than just put parts of the information in the respective views, I mean just hard coding all this which I think is easy but might get messy once the codes exceed hundreds of lines

Comment: @user2372442 1. Read the link posted by lakesh, 2. What I meant by that was, since you don't need html for the native app, send data to it using the api. It can be strings, or better, something more structured, like json or xml. I would use json.